# Cron job can't access Documents - "Tar: Desktop: Couldn't visit directory: Unknown error: -1"

Tags: security, cron, tar

I have an automated backup script that runs from a cron job. It basically tars up my home directory and pipes it to a command that writes the tarball to Amazon S3.

```
tar zcvf - -X BACKUP_EXCLUDE | /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp - ...
```

It works fine if I run from the command line, but from a cron job it fails with:

```
tar: /Users/falk/Desktop: Couldn't visit directory: Unknown error: -1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I'm guessing this is some sort of security thing, likely "Full Disk Access". (Adding Desktop to my "BACKUP_EXCLUDE" file didn't seem to help.)

Is there a way to whitelist tar to access all my files from cron? Or give cron jobs the same access as the same command executed from the terminal?

Comment: Add `cron` and `tar` to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**

Comment: That did the trick. Interestingly, I had to do this for both cron and tar, even though tar is the only program that needed to access that directory. How did you know?

Anyway, make your comment an answer, and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Actually, only cron needed it. Problem solved; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, add `cron` and `tar` to: **System Preferences** > **Security > Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**

To address your comment, "I had to do this for both cron and tar, even though tar is the only program that needed to access that directory. How did you know?":

I had read this article in the past: [How to Fix Cron Permission Issues in macOS Big Sur, Catalina, & Mojave](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on user3439894's answer:

- Go to System **Preferences > Security > Privacy > Full Disk Access**
- Click the '+' icon to add a new app
- When the "file chooser" dialog pops up, navigate to "**Macintosh HD**"
- ⌘-⇧-. to show all files and directories
- navigate to /usr/sbin/cron and select it